# Alternative Growth Ladder for non- Managerial Leaders

Tags: leadership

If some one wants to grow but does not want to choose general managerial leadership path..is it possible? in other words, does there exist an alternative to Managerial leadership ?( like technical leadership etc)

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not it's possible at your current employer specifically is a question for your employer, not random people on the Internet, but the answer in general is "Yes, there can be".

Some employers have an "engineer career track" that allows for growth and development as a technical authority within a specialist area without becoming a manager.

Comment: My employer has three tracks: a managerial one, a technical/development one, and a project management one. Larger companies may communicate this on their career websites (although it seems like my employer wants to keep this a secret - at least I couldn't find anything), and at smaller companies, much more is possible since they are more flexible - especially if you can demonstrate that you *do* have what it takes to demonstrate technical leadership.

Answer (score 2):

> If some one wants to grow but does not want to choose general managerial leadership path..is it possible?

Yes, it's quite possible. You could

- Climb your employer's technical ladder. Many employers don't have a technical ladder, and of those that do, that ladder is a tiny rickety thing that has a tendency to fall apart. A few select employers have a technical ladder because those on the management ladder recognize that the organization would quickly downslide were it not for their key technical expertise.
- Become an expert. If your employer doesn't value that, there are other employers that do. Experts in some field outperform their non-expert peers by an order of magnitude. While you will not make ten times what your non-expert peers receive, making two or three times what your non-expert peers make makes for a very nice income. Becoming an expert in technical field and simultaneously becoming an expert in salary+benefits negotiation can result in an extremely nice income.
- Become a sales person. You need to find the right employer to pull this off. The incomes of sales people is multimodal. Most sales people have a rather paltry income. A few have incomes that are better than that of a US Senator. A very select few have seven figure incomes.
- Become a consultant. In this case, you are the manager of a company of one (or two, or four, or ...). To pull this off, you need to have extreme technical expertise in some field and you need to be an very good sales person. Senatorial salaries ($174000 per year)? A decent consultant can do much better than that.